# How to get the temporary path using pytest tmpdir.as_cwd

Tags: python, pytest, temporary-directory

In a python test function

```
def test_something(tmpdir):
    with tmpdir.as_cwd() as p:
        print('here', p)
        print(os.getcwd())
```

I was expecting `p` and the `os.getcwd()` would give the same result. But in reality, `p` points to the directory of the test file whereas `os.getcwd()` points to the expected temporary file.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Can you show the `tmpdir` parameter that you are passing to the function

Comment: @DobromirM it is a fixture: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmpdir-fixture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the docs of [`py.path.as_cwd`](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html#py._path.local.LocalPath.as_cwd):

> return context manager which changes to current dir during the managed "with" context. On `__enter__` it returns the old dir.

The behaviour you are observing is thus correct:

```
def test_something(tmpdir):
    print('current directory where you are before changing it:', os.getcwd())
    # the current directory will be changed now
    with tmpdir.as_cwd() as old_dir:
        print('old directory where you were before:', old_dir)
        print('current directory where you are now:', os.getcwd())
    print('you now returned to the old current dir', os.getcwd())
```

Just remember that `p` in your example is not the "new" current dir you are changing to, it's the "old" one you changed from.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmpdir-fixture)

> You can use the tmpdir fixture which will provide a temporary
>   directory unique to the test invocation, created in the base temporary
>   directory.

Whereas, `getcwd` stands for Get Current Working directory, and returns the directory from which your python process has been started.